# Instaloader not using --login?

Tags: python, instaloader

I've downloaded instaloader, and i'm trying to download a private profile and use the --login command to make a session file. However each time i put it in and enter the password it gives

C:\Users\Admin>instaloader --login=[username]
Session file does not exist yet - Logging in.
Enter Instagram password for [username]:
Fatal error: Login: Checkpoint required. Point your browser to https://www.instagram.com/challenge/action/AXGuCLDw08ak1xL-nzC1EdeYaUZuNDCDdJLsZSjuT3a4TxwSkrKj6OG-77SMRHAo2CsMQjc/Afx6kfjbgTg3Tmb5W--o1GzGyfOECcJRR88oNNNxREGZ4B_j_OMS8PRwly7iNKMvjq8NSNVGVdps9w/ffc_8nnBo8P7mQPIddaWRqF7re0nB5zEdRbrTLKyDf6YhgNKyNwqiOit91LJj9qwd9zL/ - follow the instructions, then retry.

i follow it to a "is this you?" screen, say it is and then retry. It still gives the same response.

Is there another way to create a session file?

Comment: Did you later fix this